# how to use silverlight-selenium to automate silverlight applications using Selenium and java

Tags: java, silverlight, selenium-rc

Am exploring in automating silverlight applications using silverlight-selenium
with reference to the following post.
http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/ . In this they had mentioned 'silverlight-selenium RC client extension is currently available for the following Selenium RC client drivers: Java and .Net.'

Is it possible to use Selenium and Java with the silverlight-selenium.jar to automate silverlight applications ?

If yes, how to do that..? Any Suggestions..?

Thanks in Advance.